# Compare decision variables to floating values

Tags: python, drake

I'm currently working on a trajectory optimization problem that involves binary actuators. In order to avoid solving an MINLP I do not simply optimize over the states and control inputs but instead, assume that each of the binary actuators alternates between the states "on" and "off" and optimize over the duration of those intervals. I will call the array containing the decision variable h (an N by 2 matrix in the particular case below).

A minimal example using a double integrator that has two control inputs that enact a positive or negative force on the system respectively would be:

[image: state space model of the minimal example]

Here I model the state trajectory as some train of 3rd order polynomial.
I particularly do not want to merge these actuators into one with the states -1,0,1 since the more general system I'd like to apply this to also has more binary actuators. I add some additional constraints such as connecting the polynomials continuously and differentiably; enforce that the sum of all intervals is equal to the desired final time; enforce initial and final state constraints and finally enforce the dynamics of the system.
My initial idea was to then enforce the dynamics at constant intervals, i.e.:

[image]

However, the issue here is that any of the actuators could be in any arbitrary interval for some time t. Since the intervals can shrink to duration zero one actuator might be in the last interval while the other one remains in the first. I.e. **the value of a decision variable (time duration) changes which decision variables are dependent on each other**. This is more or less manifested in drake by the fact that I cannot do a comparison such as Tau < t if Tau is a drake expression and t is some number. The code snippet is:

```
    # Enforce dynamics at the end of each control interval
    for t in np.arange(0, Tf, dt_dyn):
        # Find the index of the interval that is active for each actuator
        t_ctrl = np.cumsum(h, axis=0)
        intervals = (t_ctrl < t)
        idxs = np.sum(intervals, axis=0)
        # If the idx is even the actuator is off, otherwise its on
        prog.AddConstraint(eq(qdd(q_a, t, dt_state),
                              continuous_dynamics(q(q_a, t, dt_state),
                                                  qd(q_a, t, dt_state),
                                                  [idxs[0] % 2, idxs[1] % 2])))
```

and the resulting error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 92, in <module>
        intervals = (t_ctrl < t)
    RuntimeError: You should not call `__bool__` / `__nonzero__` on `Formula`. If you are trying to make a map with `Variable`, `Expression`, or `Polynomial` as keys (and then access the map in Python), please use pydrake.common.containers.EqualToDict`.
```

In the end, my question is more of a conceptual than technical nature: Does drake support this dependence of the "dependence of decision variables on the values" in some other way? Or is there a different way I can transcribe my problem to avoid the ambiguity in which interval my actuators are for some given time?

I've also linked to the overall script that implements the minimal example [here](https://pastebin.com/ksfN4ibM)

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that `intervals = (t_ctrl < t)` is a vector of dtype `Formula`, not a vector of dtype `Variable(type=BINARY)`, so you can't actually sum it up.  To do an arithmetic sum, you'd need to change that line to an `np.vectorize`-wrapped function that calls something like `if_then_else(t_argument < t_constant, 0.0, 1.0)` in order to have it be an `Expression`-valued vector, at which which would be sum-able.

That won't actually help you, though, since you cannot do `%` (modular) arithmetic on symbolic expressions anyway, so the `% 2.0 == 0.0` stuff will raise an exception once you make it that far.

I suspect that you'll need a different approach to encoding the problem into variables, but unfortunately an answer there is beyond my skill level at the moment.

Comment: Actually summing the expressions up is no problem. It's calling the boolean comparison that is the problem. The t_ctrl vector looks something like this: 

``[[Variable('h(0,0)', Continuous) Variable('h(0,1)', Continuous)]
 [<Expression "(h(0,0) + h(1,0))"> <Expression "(h(0,1) + h(1,1))">]
 [<Expression "(h(0,0) + h(1,0) + h(2,0))">
  <Expression "(h(0,1) + h(1,1) + h(2,1))">]
 [<Expression "(h(0,0) + h(1,0) + h(2,0) + h(3,0))">
  <Expression "(h(0,1) + h(1,1) + h(2,1) + h(3,1))">]]`` 

for a minimal example. I just cannot execute the comparison to each Expression element.

Comment: Right, my comment was about the `intervals` line.  The clause `t < t_ctrl` is valid, but returns a `Formula`.  To do arithmetic on that valuel (the `np.sum` on the next line), you need it to return an `Expression` from the comparison, i.e., `if_then_else(t < t_ctrl, 1.0, 0.0)`.

But the main point still stands -- the `%` operation is not supported at all.